# C++ - How to use a comparator in priority queue within a Class

Tags: c++11, priority-queue

I am writing a Dijsktra program as per Cormen's book. Here, I have a class **Graph** which has a method **dijsktra**. I need to use a priority queue, ***Q*** inside this method. There are two arrays shortest[] and pred[]. This ***Q*** should sort the vertices based on shortest[] values.
Each node is represented as int.

I am getting an error in declaring a priority Queue with a comparator.  
Any Help is much appreciated.

```
class Graph {
private:
    vector<int> vertex;
    map<int, vector<int> > adjlist;
    int *shortest,*pred;
public:
    Graph(int V){
        fore(i,V) { vertex.pb(i); }
        shortest = new int[V];
        pred = new int[V];
    }
    struct Comp {                     // Error!
        Comp(Graph& g): graph(g){     // Error!
        }
        Graph& graph;
        bool operator()(int i1, int i2) {
            return graph->shortest[i1] > graph->shortest[i2];
        }
    };
    Comp comp;
    void dijsktra(int s);
 };
    void Graph::dijsktra(int s) {
        int n = vertex.size();
        fore(i,n) {
            shortest[i] = 99;
            pred[i] = 0;
        }
        shortest[s] = 0;

        priority_queue<int,vector<int>, Comp> Q(comp); // Error!

    }
```

**[EDIT]**
Tried various methods. I believe error is in adding a comparator
Error:

```
dag.cpp: In constructor ‘Graph::Graph(int)’:
dag.cpp:15:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘Graph::Comp::Comp()’
  Graph(int V){
              ^
dag.cpp:15:14: note: candidates are:
dag.cpp:21:3: note: Graph::Comp::Comp(Graph&)
   Comp(Graph& g): graph(g){
   ^
dag.cpp:21:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
dag.cpp:20:9: note: constexpr Graph::Comp::Comp(const Graph::Comp&)
  struct Comp {
         ^
dag.cpp:20:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
dag.cpp:20:9: note: constexpr Graph::Comp::Comp(Graph::Comp&&)
dag.cpp:20:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: Provide error message

Comment: Write using a `multi_map` as your priority queue to start.  Get that working, then worry about optimization.

Comment: Fix this: `Comp comp;`If you can help it, compile with clang++ next time. The error messages are more useful than the ones provided by gcc

Comment: `Graph(int V) : comp(*this) {`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik : Changing constructor to `Graph(int V) : comp(*this)` compiles successfully. Thanks.